# ReportLab and Python Imaging Library images from memory issue

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, reportlab

I've run into an issue I can't seem to figure out with PIL and reportlab. Specifically, I would like to use drawImage on a canvas in reportlab using a PIL Image object.

In the past I've inserted images into reportlab documents from the web using raw data, StringIO and reportlab's ImageReader class. Unfortunately, ImageReader takes a file name or a file buffer like object.

The ultimate goal is to be able to put QR codes, (which are PIL objects) into the reportlab PDFs. One thing that does work is the following:

```
    size, qrcode = PyQrcodec.encode('http://www.google.com')
    qrcode.save("img.jpeg")
    self.pdf.drawImage(ImageReader("img.jpeg"), 25, 25, width=125, height=125)
    self.pdf.showPage()
```

This saves the image and then reads it into the pdf. Obviously doing it like this doesn't make sense.

My efforts are compounded by the relatively long development history of reportlab which makes finding the answers relevant to the latest version (2.4).

Thanks for the help.

(By the way, I'm using 1.1.6 PIL)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it does look like it should work, it really doesn't. I finally was able to track down the problem, and it was in the _isPILImage() function. The problem is that "Image.Image" is actually "from PIL import Image" whereas my object is actually just from Image. I would have assumed they were the same, but in any case isinstance doesn't evaluate them as the same. My hack solution was to change _isPILImage(fileName): ... to

```
519 def _isPILImage(im):
520     import Image as PIL_Image
521     try:
522         return isinstance(im,Image.Image) or isinstance(im, PIL_Image.Image)
523     except ImportError:
524         return 0
```

That solves my error. Since you pointed me in the right direction I originally tried to post this as a comment then accept your answer, but it doesn't allow enough characters.

Thank you for the input! If you can think of a more elegant way to fix this... (I tried to wrap the Image.Image object in a PIL Image object) let me know!

Comment: By the way, the function above is in lib/utils.py in reportlab.

Comment: +1 good catch. The PIL installer putting PIL modules in a PIL folder off the site path is a questionable decision, but ReportLab is making a worse mistake by relying on it. It should just be importing Image. I worked around the problem by monkey-patching from the outside: import Image myself, and saying `reportlab.lib.utils.Image= Image`.

Comment: @bobince has the right idea here.  ReportLab makes some really bad assumptions about PIL location, but it's cleaner to patch after import with `reportlab.lib.utils.Image=Image` than to fiddle with ReportLab code and complicate your deployment.

Comment: P.S. Great catch, @philipk!  Has this been reported as a bug to ReportLab?

Comment: I'm not sure - I think I spent about 20 minutes trying to make a bug report, but never really figured out how to do so. (Not positive though, it was so long ago)

Comment: @bobince's comment should be correct answer to this problem :)

Comment: The `_isPILImage` code is wrong.  `ImportError` will not be caught by the `try...except` because it is outside of the `try...except`.  The `isinstance()` check could also be written as `return isinstance(im, (Image.Image, PIL_Image.Image))`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source for ReportLab 2.4, it seems that ImageReader will accept a PIL Image object as "filename".

```
def _isPILImage(im):
    try:
        return isinstance(im,Image.Image)
    except ImportError:
        return 0

class ImageReader(object):
    "Wraps up either PIL or Java to get data from bitmaps"
    _cache={}
    def __init__(self, fileName):
        if isinstance(fileName,ImageReader):
            self.__dict__ = fileName.__dict__   #borgize
            return
        #start wih lots of null private fields, to be populated by
        #the relevant engine.
        self.fileName = fileName
        self._image = None
        self._width = None
        self._height = None
        self._transparent = None
        self._data = None
        if _isPILImage(fileName):
            self._image = fileName
            self.fp = getattr(fileName,'fp',None)
            try:
                self.fileName = self._image.fileName
            except AttributeError:
                self.fileName = 'PILIMAGE_%d' % id(self)
```

Comment: So `self.pdf.drawImage(ImageReader(qrcode), 25, 25, width=125, height=125)` ought to work, assuming the rest of the arguments to `drawImage` are appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

weired
the documentation claims that drawImage and drawInlineImage work the same way, but it works with drawInlineImage out of the box, and do not work in drawImage

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, using plotly, BytesIO and reportlab. It puts an image in the pdf from memory, without having to save it on disk first.

```
import io
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Image

image_in_memory = io.BytesIO()
figure = go.Figure(data=data)  # as it's not part of the question I'm leaving data out
figure.write_image(image_in_memory, scale=5, width=1000, height=400)
pdf_image = Image(image_in_memory, width=400, height=160)
pdf_document = SimpleDocTemplate(path, title='Title')
pdf_document.multiBuild([pdf_image])
```